# Negatively correlated random variables Chebyshev bound?

Tags: probability, inequality, distribution-tails

It is quite well known that the Chernoff bound applies to negatively correlated binary random variables (see e.g. Theorem 1.16 [here](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~doerr/7438_chap01.pdf)). Does there exist a reference for Chebyshev-type bound for negatively correlated binary variables?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment on my answer, the main question is *why* you need a reference, if you agree it's "fairly straightforward." Is it for a research paper? In which case you can just state it as a fact (or, if you feel you owe it to the reader, include a short proof "for completeness"). There is no need to provide a reference for all the statements -- for instance, you wouldn't provide one for Markov's inequality or Chebyshev, and this is of the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need a reference, instead of just deriving it or stating it as a fact? If the r.v.'s $(X_k)_{1\leq k \leq n}$ are negatively correlated *(and have finite variance)*, then you have
$$
\operatorname{Var}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{Var} X_k
$$
*(since all covariances are non-positive: expand the variance on the LHS);* and therefore you can use Chebyshev's inequality directly:
$$
\forall a>0,\qquad \mathbb{P}\left\{\left\lvert\sum_{k=1}^n X_k - \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}X_k\right\rvert > a\right\}\leq \frac{\operatorname{Var}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k}{a^2} \leq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{Var}X_k}{a^2} \tag{$\dagger$}
$$

Comment: The derivation is fairly straightforward and I was more concerned about providing the appropriate citation.

Comment: As you say, it is pretty straightforward. Either state it as a fact (folklore? Immediate fact?) or include a short proof "for completeness". (Not everything needs a reference...) @user1246462